# Implementation of fgets() function in PHP

Tags: php

I'm usinng Windows operating system and new to PHP.
Namely I'm trying to implement php function fgets() in php file:

```
$file = fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/Chapter02/test.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }

fclose($file);
```

I have created test.txt file with the following content:

> Hello, this is a test file.
>   There are three lines here.
>   This is the last line.

as example from http://www.w3schools.com/

Both files,  .php and .txt are located in a directory:

C:/wamp/www/Chapter02/

but after execution this php file, is not showing anything, and shall show:

> Hello, this is a test file.
>   There are three lines here.
>   This is the last line.

I suppose, I'm making a mistake in a path "$DOCUMENT_ROOT/Chapter02/test.txt", but I really don't know where the mistake is...

I would highly appreciate your help:)

kind regards,

Ivana

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com)

Answer (score 1):

Possible pitfalls:

- Your document not existing (your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable may not be set)
- Your document being empty

fgets() works in exactly the same way across all main PHP platforms, so I am pretty sure that your problem is on the existence of the file rather than the actual reading code (which looks good)

Try to var_dump($DOCUMENT_ROOT) and manually check if the file exists (using file_exists()). This might uncover the bug.

By the way, W3Schools is a horrible website to learn from, as much as I hate to say this. A lot of their info is either out of date, broken, or completely ambiguous.

Comment: This particular error is occurring because w3schools' tutorial assumes that `register_globals` is available and enabled (and, thus, that the variable will be populated from `$_SERVER`).

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. convert $DOCUMENT_ROOT to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

Comment: I have checked according to your inputs and tried var_dump($DOCUMENT_ROOT) and is working, but by using file_exists() with data file $DOCUMENT_ROOT/Chapter02/test.txt (I made this file personally:), and the document is not empty)) I'm receiving the message, that the file doesn't exist, I'm a little bit surprised..., What I should do further? and what site should I follow instead of W3Schools, pls. give me a suggestion

Comment: var_dump($DOCUMENT_ROOT) should've returned a full directory - that actually exists. If it returned NULL, or bool(false), or anything else , it means that your W3S snippet assumed that `register_globals` were on, and they weren't. Your best bet is to replace $DOCUMENT_ROOT with the full path without relying on a server variable for now, and to change it once it works.

Comment: I have also tried as you have written, I put the full "C:/wamp/www/Chapter02/test.txt","r" but it will not still display the content of txt file, I have also modified php.ini by changing the register_globals to on, but is still not working...have you any new suggestion?

Comment: I have finally spotted where the problem was...By mistake I have named my file test.txt.txt:)))))) so that "c:/wamp/www/Chapter02/test.txt" simply didn't exist....but "c:/wamp/www/Chapter02/test.txt.txt" exited, huh I have lost 1 day on this... thank you anyway for patience, regards

Answer (score 0):

Change `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Unless you set `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` yourself, you should use the latter, which is set from the server configuration.